# Incorrect argument passed to addEventListener to a HTMLElement using a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener, nodelist

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Y8FU/

I'm querying all **tr.tableWinkelwagen-productItem** in this table using:

```
var productItemAll = document.querySelectorAll(".tableWinkelwagen-productItem")
```

This is the tabel:

```
                <table class="tableWinkelwagen">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product(en)</th>
                        <th>Prijs</th>
                        <th>Aantal</th>
                        <th>Totaal</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tableWinkelwagen-productItem" data-id="1">
                        <td>Treinreis Utrecht - Boedapest <br> <small>05/08/2014 - 05/08/2014</small></td>
                        <td>€<span class="priceUnit">170</span>,-</td>
                        <td><div class="boxNumbers"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign boxNumbers-min"></i> <input type="text" class="boxNumbers-input priceAmount" placeholder=""> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign boxNumbers-plus"></i></div></td>
                        <td>€<span class="priceTotal">340</span>,-</td>
                        <td><a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="tableWinkelwagen-productItem" data-id="1">
                        <td>Treinreis Utrecht - Boedapest <br> <small>05/08/2014 - 05/08/2014</small></td>
                        <td>€<span class="priceUnit">170</span>,-</td>
                        <td><div class="boxNumbers"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign boxNumbers-min"></i> <input type="text" class="boxNumbers-input priceAmount" placeholder=""> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign boxNumbers-plus"></i></div></td>
                        <td>€<span class="priceTotal">340</span>,-</td>
                        <td><a href="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><strong>Totaal</strong></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>€<span>340</span>,-</td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

This, of course, gives me a nodeList with the 2 tr's.

I'm then adding an eventListener to each of the **i.boxNumbers-min** inside a tr using this code:

```
    function addEventListenerToMinPlus(){

        var x, y

        for(var i = 0; i < productItemAll.length; i++){

            x = productItemAll[i].querySelector(".boxNumbers-min")
            x.addEventListener("click", function(){updateProduct(i)})

            console.log(x)


        }

    }
```

The console prints out both tr's fine but when i execute the function updateProduct(i), initiated with a click i get a popop with the value 2 and not "0" and "1".

```
    function updateProduct(jow){

        alert(jow)


    }
```

Why do i always get the value "2" and not "0" or "1" when clicking on the **i.boxNumbers-min** buttons?

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Y8FU/

Comment: Think carefully, what might the value of `i` be at the time you actually click a `td`.

Comment: I don't get it, i'm setting a different i on every x, so the parameter passed should be 1 or 2?

Comment: It looks the very same letter `i` to me ; ). When you have an anonymous function like this, _it is not executed_ before it is called. Clicking on a `td` triggers the function call, at that time `i` will be `2`, since you haven't stored the value. Anyway, I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v4xz5/) for you, which shows, how you can get this done... Maybe reading about [functions and function scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) would also help?

Comment: Ok, thx... but i'm not getting it at the moment, it's a really deep closure inside a closure, etc...